# Can I use parse with on an existing app that already connected to mysql?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, sdk, backend

I'd like to connect a specific part of my mobile app to parse.com in order to save work on the backend. Is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course.  You can connect to as many web services and databases you need to.  You just need the code/sdk for each web service or database you want to interact with.